How to see the logs of failed snakemake jobs immediately in stderr - instead of log file
I'm running snakemake inside kubernetes with argocd. When a job errors, snakemake says that the logs of the failed job are in a log file. Now I can't easily look this logfile up because argocd doesn't allow this.
I want the failed job logs to be shown in the normal log output. How can I do this?

Add the command line option --show-failed-logs. From the docs:
--show-failed-logs
  Automatically display logs of failed jobs.

  Default: False

